# jqGrid-Get the value of selected row that is to be deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid

Hi I'm new to jQuery and have referred this link http://www.phpgrid.org/demo-center/ to implement Gridview.

I want to check which button is clicked by the user from the alert box(Delete or Cancel),if it is delete button then I want to perform some backend operations and for that I need to get the value of particular row.
so how do I handle delete button event of the alert box..?
Please any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [on_delete event](http://www.phpgrid.org/docs/#Grid_Events) api in docs.
In this callback function, you can write your backend logic in php.